# Deep array !empty check in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to check array value, but when array is empty, I get this: Error: Cannot use string offset as an array

```
if (!empty($items[$i]['tickets']['ticket'][0]['price']['eur'])) {  //do something  }
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Have you read this: http://informationideas.com/news/2006/06/14/fatal-error-cannot-use-string-offset-as-an-array-in/

Comment: thanks for the link. I had read it, but still no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the variable is set, then if it is an array and then check if the array's element is set. The statements of the if will be executed in order and will break when one is false.

```
if(isset($items) && is_array($items) && isset($items[$i]['tickets']['ticket'][0]['price']['eur'])) {
    //jep it's there
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just try it (extra sipmle variant):

```
if (!isset($items[$i]['tickets']['ticket'][0]['price']['eur'])) {
   // do action
}
```